# Is there a Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.7.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi4py, visual-c++

I know that there is a "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.4" but is there, currently or planned, a Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.7? My problem is that when I try to install mpi4py it fails to build a wheel.

Comment: ...for Python 3.7-specific build documentation for Windows, the canonical source is https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/PCbuild/readme.txt

Answer (score 1):

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

according to this message goto the website, scroll down and download -> Older versions -> Redistributables and Build Tools -> Microsoft Build Tools 2015
install `visualcppbuildtools_full.exe`

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to install package `mpi4py` then you can download already built binary from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mpi4py) website and install it with pip. Take care which version you are download, it needs to be appropriate for your python, but you will get informative error even if you pick the wrong one.

Install package using:

```
python -m pip install path_to_whl/mpi4py‑3.0.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

As for the no MS Visual C++ you can download the missing [requirement here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.0)

For `mpi4py` specifically have you tried:

`pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py` ([from here](https://pypi.org/project/mpi4py/))

I hope this helps.

Comment: It would help to point to documentation demonstrating that the version of Visual C++ you linked is the same one used for the official build of Python 3.7.1. `pip install` (when upstream hasn't already packaged binaries) requires you to have that specific Visual C++ release installed *first*.

Comment: Yes, when I try to install it from there it says "Failed building a wheel for mpi4py". I have MS-MPI installed, so I think the problem comes from the MS Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: Hmm have you installed the latest version of the MS Visual C++ compiler

Comment: @JoeTilsed, the "latest version" may be *too new*. Only the exact version used by Python upstream in guaranteed to build binaries with an identical ABI, which is why an answer that doesn't specify where you found the documentation indicating that the specific version of MSVC++ you recommended to the OP is the one Python upstream used for the 3.7.1 release is suspect.

Comment: @JoeTilsed, ...given as determining the specific version of MSVC++ needed to build libraries for Python 3.7.1 is *the whole thing this question is about*, just specifying "the latest one" is awfully vague.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it was a suggestion that maybe the OP could try, not a solution